# Is VACUUM FULL necessary on a DROP TABLE / TRUNCATE approach for a datawarehouse

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, postgresql-9.6

We are updating a datawarehouse on a weekly basis using a series of

```
TRUNCATE source_table1 
COPY source_table1 FROM [...]
```

... for data import
and:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table
CREATE TABLE my_table AS SELECT [...]
```

for table updates.

We end our update process with a `VACUUM FULL [VERBOSE] ANALYZE`, because, as the documentation suggests, `VACUUM` should be done when a significant share of tuples has been updated or removed.
Here, as it is a share of 100% for all tables, we reasonably thought that `VACUUM` should be applied.

As we see the ouptput of the verbose option, it seems that Postgresql has not much to do, as every table `VACUUM`ed gives:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.table345"
INFO:  "table345": found 0 removable, 9831703 nonremovable row versions in 62538 pages
DETAIL : 0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
```

I guess that on the contrary `ANALYZE` is more than helpfull to update the internal statistics.
Most tables are 10-100m rows big.

But we were wondering if `VACUUM FULL` or just `VACUUM` were really necessary in that case?

(Or may be the whole update process (DROP / CREATE TABLE AS) is not the right way to do?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Point about TRUNCATE/COPY

Unrelated note, depending on the WAL level, wrapping the `TRUNCATE` and `COPY` in the same transaction things *may* go faster, because WAL will be skipped. Further the CTAS will always skip most WAL.

> In minimal level, WAL-logging of some bulk operations can be safely skipped, which can make those operations much faster (see Section 14.4.7). Operations in which this optimization can be applied include 
>   [source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html)
>
> - **CREATE TABLE AS**
> - CREATE INDEX
> - CLUSTER
> - **COPY into tables that were created or truncated in the same transaction**

```
    BEGIN;
      TRUNCATE source_table1 
      COPY source_table1 FROM [...]
    COMMIT;
```

## Issue of `VACUUM FULL`

1. There is no need to do a `VACUUM FULL` on a new table. The table is already new in those transactions so there is no need to rewrite it, as `FULL` does. There is also no need to `VACUUM` it because there are no movable rows that VACUUM will act on. When you run `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE`, you can see nothing was removable, and no dead rows were removed. `VACUUM FULL` can be useful if

   1. you're staging `INSERTS` though a temp table, and adding them in batches into a dirty table. Then it can often pay off at the end of the process.
   2. you're running `UPDATE` on a large batch because `UPDATE` generates new rows forcing `VACUUM` to later mark the old rows as dead.
2. A simple `ANALYZE` will work fine. This will update the *statistics* on the table.

Comment: A `VACUUM` can still be useful on the new tables to set the visibility map for the sake of index-only-scans, and the freeze map for the sake of future anti-wraparound vacuums (which might occur at inopportune times if left to themselves).  But correct, a `VACUUM FULL` is never going to be useful for the poster's case.